# Problem with csv and separator awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have issues with reading csv format like this:

```
"foo","bar foo, foo bar", foo, bar, far
"bar", "foobar foo, foo" , bar, fobar, bar
```

Technically, both lines should have 5 fields accordingly with separator `,`.

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' resolver.csv 
6
6
```

This is where problem goes. AWK treats `,` as a separator between quotations marks, and provide non accurate results. Giving the separator like `-F '","'` makes things only worse.

```
awk -F, '{print $3}' test.csv 
 foo bar"
 foo"
```

Any work around?

Comment: Yes: don't use awk. Use a csv parser. Awk has no knowledge of csv, all it knows is how to split a line on field separators.

Comment: e.g. python has a csv module that can parse most CSV formats. I'm pretty sure that perl also has one.

Comment: This, also, is far harder than you're expecting.  There are a couple of projects I've found to do this, the first is this: https://github.com/geoffroy-aubry/awk-csv-parser

Comment: @xrobau thanks for the link. I am currently checking `csvtool` from Debian repo's, and seems it is doing the job properly..